# "Permission Denied" Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx

I trying install web-app "Bookstack".
OS - Alt Server 10.1 (like a Debian)
I almost reach the finish line, but i have emty page, when i trying open start page.
/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2023/05/01 02:10:16 [error] 8093#8093: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/bookstack/storage/framework/views/444e2e0a8c776f8bed9002e3000a037539df392e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(270): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/bookst...', 190)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/bookst...', 190)
#2 /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(190): file_put_contents('/var/www/bookst...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)
#3 /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(185): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/bo...; PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/bookstack/storage/framework/views/444e2e0a8c776f8bed9002e3000a037539df392e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:190
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(270): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/bookst...', 190)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/bookst...', 190)
```

That assure me, that i didn't give rights on folders, but i did.
This example on folder "vendor" that was in error.

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 aws
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 bacon
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 barryvdh
drwxr-xr-x  2 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:54 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 brick
drwxr-xr-x  2 _nginx _nginx 20480 апр 24 22:50 composer
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 dasprid
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 dflydev
drwxr-xr-x  8 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:54 doctrine
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 dompdf
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 dragonmantank
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 egulias
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 fruitcake
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 graham-campbell
drwxr-xr-x  6 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 guzzlehttp
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 intervention
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 knplabs
drwxr-xr-x  6 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 laravel
drwxr-xr-x 10 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 league
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 masterminds
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 monolog
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 mtdowling
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 nesbot
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 nette
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 nikic
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:54 nunomaduro
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 onelogin
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 paragonie
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 phenx
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 phpoption
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 phpseclib
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 pragmarx
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 predis
drwxr-xr-x 10 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 psr
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 psy
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 ralouphie
drwxr-xr-x  4 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:14 ramsey
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 robrichards
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 sabberworm
drwxr-xr-x  9 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 socialiteproviders
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:54 ssddanbrown
drwxr-xr-x 29 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 22:54 symfony
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 tijsverkoyen
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 vlucas
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 voku
drwxr-xr-x  3 _nginx _nginx  4096 апр 24 21:44 webmozart
```

What i can do more?

I tried clear php artisan cache and also typical problems with "permission denied", that i found in Google search.
But nothing helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close, just the wrong folder. If you look closer at your error

```
2023/05/01 02:10:16 [error] 8093#8093: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/bookstack/storage/framework/views/444e2e0a8c776f8bed9002e3000a037539df392e.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/bookstack/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:190
```

It states that you got the permission error when running `file_put_contents(/var/www/bookstack/storage/framework/views/444e2e0a8c776f8bed9002e3000a037539df392e.php)`.
This means that the issue is the permissions on your storage folder, and not the vendor folder. So you should ensure that the `/var/www/bookstack/storage/framework/views` folder exists, and ensure it has proper permissions ( I usually give 775 for directories and 664 for files in storage )